# how to run ffmpeg command(windows) in java

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I executed the below FFMPEG terminal command in command prompt successfully. But I am unable to execute this command in my java program. I can execute all other ffmpeg commands which doesn't have double quotation marks, in my java program. Here I have confusing only with double quotation marks("...").

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:C:\\journalism\\videos\\vid1.ts|C:\\journalism\\videos\\vid2.ts" -c copy C:\\journalism\\videos\\output.mp4
```

I can execute above in command prompt successfully. But I tried as below in my java code.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg -i 'concat:C:\\journalism\\videos\\vid1.ts|C:\\journalism\\videos\\vid2.ts' -c copy C:\\journalism\\videos\\output.mp4");
```

Even I tried by replaced the double quotation marks("...") with single quotation marks('...'). But not succeeded.

Can anyone please help me to get out of this issue...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found answer for myself. Instead of using String object, I used String array as below, then the command executed successfully.

```
String[] cmd={"C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg","-i", "concat:C:\\journalism\\videos\\vid1.ts|C:\\journalism\\videos\\vid2.ts", "-c", "copy", "C:\\journalism\\videos\\output.mp4"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Answer (score 2):

My program is running, i just use as below. Hope it help you :

String cmd = "ffmpeg -i http://117.103.224.78/videoinput/Video1.mp4 -s 1920x1080 -c:a copy D:\\tmp\\Video2.mp4";

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same, this code did the trick.

```
String exeLocation = "\"C:\\Program Files\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg\"";
String extractFileName = "test.mp4";
String extractFullPath = "C:\\ac3" + "\\" + extractFileName;
String dest = "C:\\\\ac3\\\\output.mp4";

String cmd = exeLocation + " -i " + extractFullPath + " -c copy " + dest ;
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```